# How can I give row and column names to Scipy's csr_matrix?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I don't know if it's possible, and it's possibly a naive question, but how can I set the equivalent of R's `rownames()` and `colnames()` to a `scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix` ?

I saw that `my_matrix.dtype.names` doesn't work here, and I can't find any "index" equivalend for such sparse matrix...

Moreover, `pandas.sparse.*` is not an option here, because of some open issue...

Thank you so much for your help,

Comment: `dtype.names` refer to `fields` of a structured array.  Think of column names/headers in a CSV table.  You can't do much math across fields.  And you can't use that kind of dtype in sparse matrices.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll have to maintain the names separately, as none of scipy's sparse formats support named indexing. This might look like:

```
foo = csr_matrix(...)
row_names = np.array(...)
col_names = np.array(...)

# index by name:
row_idx, = np.where(row_names == "my row")
col_idx, = np.where(col_names == "my col")
foo[row_idx, col_idx]
```

Comment: I wonder if a dictionary look would be faster?  The sparse `dok` format is actually a dictionary, with index tuples as keys.

Comment: Efficiency depends on the size and sparsity of the matrix, but yeah, dictionaries of name->index would also work. DOK format doesn't help, though, as it's keys must be pairs of integers.

Comment: But he might make his own dictionary with tuples of the labels as keys.  It won't give him any math abilities.

Answer (score -1):

See the package ["SSparseMatrix"](https://pypi.org/project/SSparseMatrix/). (The package uses SciPy's sparse matrices.)

Here is a creation and row-selection example (in a Python session):

```
>>> from SSparseMatrix import *
>>> mat = [[1, 0, 0, 3], [4, 0, 0, 5], [0, 3, 0, 5], [0, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 5]]
>>> smat = SSparseMatrix(mat)
>>> smat.set_column_names(["a", "b", "c", "d"])
<5x4 SSparseMatrix (sparse matrix with named rows and columns) of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 8 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format, and fill-in 0.4>
>>> smat.set_row_names(["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"])
<5x4 SSparseMatrix (sparse matrix with named rows and columns) of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 8 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format, and fill-in 0.4>
>>> smat.print_matrix()
===================================
  |       a       b       c       d
-----------------------------------
A |       1       .       .       3
B |       4       .       .       5
C |       .       3       .       5
D |       .       .       1       .
E |       .       .       .       5
===================================
>>> smat[["A","B"],:].print_matrix()
===================================
  |       a       b       c       d
-----------------------------------
A |       1       .       .       3
B |       4       .       .       5
===================================
```